# I've separated my front bumper and now put it in the same collection but both objects are giving different shading between them

Tags: modeling

[image]

Objects are showing different shading even when I moved them to the same collection.

Comment: Shading isn't a property of the collection the object is in, but of the shader that is being used.  Are you sure both objects have the same shader settings?

Answer (score 3):

Collections aren’t for managing materials.
Go to the Materials tab of the Properties editor instead:[image: Materials tab]

Then, check that the same shader is set for both the hood and the other thing (select each in turn and observe what is displayed in their material slots).

For more information, please see the Materials information in the Blender Manual, particularly [Material Assignment](http://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/assignment.html).

Comment: Fixed it , it was the normals. ;) @zarghulthewizard thanks for your help.

Comment: Fixed it , it was the normals. ;)